# Exploring where and in what way the Qur'an details the experience of loosing confidence or faith

Tags: doubts, fear

I am writing a book that explores how we can over-think and out-smart ourselves.  I am researching a chapter that looks back and details specific examples of where that has happened in our sacred texts, philosophy, science and the like.